# PHP Getting valuse of Arrays that are inside Objects

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm running a query that looks like this:

```
 $results = $DB2->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auth_user as count WHERE email='" . $DB2->escape_str($email) . "';");
```

It's returning an object that looks like this:

```
DB_Cache Object
(
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [COUNT(*)] => 0
            )

    )

[row] => Array
    (
        [COUNT(*)] => 0 // I WANT YOU!
    )

[num_rows] => 1
[q_count] => 1
[fields] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

I am trying to access the [count] array value using this:

```
$results->row['count'];
```

It's not returning anything. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `count` array value, though there might be a `COUNT(*)` one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your SQL statement from `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(*) AS count`

Comment: Thanks a ton! Totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$results->row["COUNT(*)"]
```

The value between `[]` indicates the key of the array. You have to use exactly that key in order to access the array's value.